# iPhone: UIScrollView not scrolling when adding item via IB

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make a very simple scrolling page via IB. What I've got is a `UIImageView` at the top and 2 `UIImageViews` at the bottom, with a `UITextView` in the middle. I've disabled the scrolling in the `UITextView` as I won't the whole page to scroll up and down including the `UIImageViews`.

Can anyone tell me why the `UIScrollView` won't scroll up and down? All of the items above are subviews of `UIScrollView` via `IB`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only scroll in a `UIScrollView` if the `contentSize` is larger than the frame. Have you set this?

Comment: No I haven't. Can you tell me where I can set this in IB. Thanks.

Comment: you can't do this in IB you have to do it within the ViewController holding the scrollview with the line of code `[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width,height)]`