# UITextField value from Static UITableViewCell in UITableView not showing up

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, nsarray

I have the following code in a save method:

```
NSArray *cells = [tbleView visibleCells];
UITableViewCell *aCell;
UITextField *medField;

for (int i=1; i<cells.count; i++) //0 = text 
{
    aCell = (UITableViewCell *) [cells objectAtIndex:i];
    medField = (UITextField *)[[aCell contentView] viewWithTag:i];
    NSLog(@"%@", medField.text);
}
```

In my TableView I have 7 static cells, the first row and last rows/cells do not have text fields, cells 1-5 do have an `UITextField`. When I enter text in the fields the debugger shows everything is fine until I enter text in the 5th cell, then all values, which previously worked and including 5 return null.  Everything is fine til I hit that 5th cell.  I made sure the tag is right, tried cutting the cells.count -1, tried making i<=cells.count, it has to be something simple I am doing wrong here, but I am lost in it right now.

Comment: I just deleted 5th cell and now works.  I was doing something weird with that cell.  I should add a cell back and try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question resides here:
[Load all cells in UITableView before scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414746/load-all-cells-in-uitableview-before-scrolling)

The problem is the keyboard hides cells.  Therefor the cell is not visible.

Man I hate problems like this!  Hope this post can help someone else.